# Java solution for next integer array permutation fails incase of a testcase involving reverse sorted array like 3,2,1 on leetcode

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, permutation

Leetcode problem:https://leetcode.com/problems/next-permutation/

The code fails when the input is in descending order like 3,2,1 even though i have provided specific case for that condition. What am i doing wrong?

```java
class Solution {
    public void nextPermutation(int[] nums) {
        int temp = 0, a, b = -1;
        for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            if (nums[i] > nums[i - 1]) {
                temp = nums[i - 1];
                b = i - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        //attempting to reverse array
        if (b == -1) {
            for (int s = 0; s < nums.length - 1; s++) {
                nums[s] = nums[s] * -1;
            }
            Arrays.sort(nums);
            for (int s = 0; s < nums.length - 1; s++) {
                nums[s] = nums[s] * -1;
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
                if (nums[i] > temp) {
                    a = nums[i];
                    nums[i] = temp;
                    nums[b] = a;
                    Arrays.sort(nums, b, nums.length - 1);
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my idea is inspired from : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuLCLgMElus&list=PLgUwDviBIf0rPG3Ictpu74YWBQ1CaBkm2&index=10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are specifically worried about the case when the array is sorted in decreasing order then the modification you are doing to the array is wrong.
For such cases, you are required to `reverse` the array or simply sort the array in `increasing` order.
But you are reversing the array incorrectly.
For example: `[4,3,2,1]` => [-4,-3,-2,-1] *(multiplying -1)* => [-4,-3,-2,-1] *(sorting (already sorted))* => [4,3,2,1] *(multiplying -1)*.
Hence, the array never gets reversed.
So, just use `Arrays.sort(nums)` for the desired result.

Comment: Yes i used that.it worked for that testcase but now other testcases where array is not sorted in decreasing order like 1,3,2 fails

Comment: Then it's a different question altogether, try to modify the part of your code where it fails.

Comment: Edit: I solved it, i just changed the indexing while sorting and it worked I'm really having a hard time remembering the syntax..thanks for your help